# How to override java variables and make the variables as mandatory fields

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, design-patterns, overriding

I have created a utility jar file called email-util.jar. The main purpose of the utility is to send email via Amazon SES or Gmail SMTP. I have used factory pattern to decide the email type. (email-util.jar will be used in multiple projects)

**EmailService.java (Interface)**

```
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO)
```

**Implementation for Amazon SES**

```
public class AmazonSimpleEmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO)
{
Amazon related stuff
}
```

**Implementation for Gmail**

```
public class GmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO)
{
Gmail related stuff
}
```

**EmailVO** will have ToAddress, FromAddress….. All email related info resides in EmailVO.
Using factory pattern I am able to create object of either AWS or Gmail and send email successfully.

Right now I have hardcoded all the configurations of Amazon SES and Gmail in their corresponding implementations. The configuration info of Amazon and Gmail is little different.

**Gmail**

- Smpt host
- Smtp port
  …

**Amazon SES**

- awsAccessKey
- awsSecretKey
- region
- connectionTimeout
- maxConnections
- socketTimeout
- maxErrorRetry  ….

But I don’t want configuration info to be hardcoded. I introduced an additional parameter to sendEmail method.

```
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO, EmailConfig config)
```

EmailConfig is a simple bean where I have the entire amazon and gmail related variables. Everything is working fine. But I have few concerns

**Quesions**

1. Is there a way we can separate Amazon SES configurations and Gmail related configurations.
2. One more issue is user doesn’t know which variables are mandatory and which variables are optional. I.e. if user opts for gmail then Region is optional. How to solve this problem
3. Any design pattern which addresses this issue

I tried creating a marker interface called EmailConfig and created two classes which implement EmailConfig.

```
AmazonSESConfig implements EmailConfig
amazonSES related variables.

GmailConfig implements EmailConfig
gmail related variables.
```

But it didn’t work out. Not able to store object of AmazonSES/Gmail in EmailConfig since it is a marker interface.

Comment: From reading the  `override` and `core` tag descriptions, I don't think those tags are appropriate here.

Comment: If the user is not aware which service is being used, and the service does not control the instance of `Email` being created, then the required fields are the union of all required fields. There is nothing else that can possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way we can separate Amazon SES configurations and Gmail
>   related configurations.

You can have two distinct classes that return configuration values but as these two providers don't rely on the same requirement, you should explicitly use this classes.

And having a common base class as you tried makes no sense :

```
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO, EmailConfig config)
```

You should have one class for Amazon and another class for Gmail with each one a distinct method :

```
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO, AmazonSESConfig config)
     ...
public Status sendEmail(Email emailVO, GmailConfig config)
```

> One more issue is user doesn’t know which variables are mandatory and
>   which variables are optional. I.e. if user opts for gmail then Region
>   is optional. How to solve this problem

If you use a distinct configuration class for gmail and another one for amazon, you can easily check that all required fields were valued at runtime.
Each implementation could do its own check.

If you want to catch the problem at compile time, you could use a step builder to force the client to fill all required fields.

You could have something as :

```
AmazonSESConfig amazonConfig = 
AmazonSESConfig.Builder().awsAccessKey(access).awsSecretKey(secret).region(region)...build();
```

where `awsAccessKey()` will return an instance of an interface that contains a `awsSecretKey()` method. The `awsSecretKey()` method will return an instance of an interface that contains a `region()` method. And so for...

If a mandatory field is not valued, the client could not call the build method as only the last one field to value will return an instance of an interface that provides the `build()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hide knowledge about particular `EmailService` implementation from user, incapsulate all configs in implementation classes and give user concrete implementation through factory.

```
 class EmailServiceFactory {

      public EmailService getService() {}      

 }
```

and you dont have to change this method signature

```
interface EmailService {

    public Status sendEmail(Email email); 

}
```